# Enable Google Cloud Messaging API with Xamarin and Azure

Tags: android, azure, xamarin, xamarin.android, azure-notificationhub

I tried to follow Microsoft Azure's [guide](https://azure.microsoft.com/da-dk/documentation/articles/xamarin-notification-hubs-push-notifications-android-gcm/) to setup Push Notification with Android. But at step 4 I am stucked, as I can not find any places to enable the API for Push Notification, as the link leads to [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/), which I can not use, since I need to provide my app for Windows too.

Azure requires GCM, but when I set it up using GCM, it fails with errorcode 401. What can I do?

Comment: FCM is the superset of frozen feature-set GCM and they support iOS, Android and web mobile clients. They do not directly support Windows clients. You might want to look at 3rd party service buses that provide a unified messaging system that support APNS, GCM/FCM, etc...  The Azure Messaging  service is one that does just that.

Comment: Yes, that's why I tried to set it up, but I can not enable GCM that way the told me to

Comment: Are you talking about enabling  GCM and creating an API key in Google Cloud Console?

Comment: I am just talking about enabling GCM API, as that is not that intuitive, as Azure says in their guide.

Comment: `enabling GCM API`? In Azure console or Googles? Have you enabled GCM and created a key based upon your app package name and signing key? You do that first in "Google API Console" first and use the resulting key in Azure's console, then you can setup GCM and Azure messaging client in your android app.

Comment: In Googles Developer Console

Comment: They have a full set of guides available that walk you through the steps: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm

Comment: Thx for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... the link leads to Firebase Cloud Messaging, which I can not use, since
>   I need to provide my app for Windows too

Is [Register your app for the Windows Store](https://azure.microsoft.com/da-dk/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-wns-push-notification/#register-your-app-for-the-windows-store)
 section in [Getting started with Notification Hubs for Windows Universal Platform Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/da-dk/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-wns-push-notification/#register-your-app-for-the-windows-store) what you are looking for? If I understood you correctly, you were looking not for Xamarin-specific code, but for how to set up a hub to push to Windows devices. If it's not correct, please clarify in comments for this answer.

> ... the problem is, that Android is based upon GCM, and they now are using
>   FCM

[Notification Hubs: how to Enable Firebase cloud messaging](https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/includes/notification-hubs-enable-firebase-cloud-messaging.md) provides information about that.

Comment: I am looking for it on all platforms, but I think Windows is easy for Xamarin and Azure

Comment: At the very top of the article there're links to how to implement it for all platforms. Follow those and you will get detailed instructions on how to set things up.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is, that Android is based upon GCM, and they now are using FCM.

Comment: Does [Notification Hubs: how to Enable Firebase cloud messaging](https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/includes/notification-hubs-enable-firebase-cloud-messaging.md) help?

Comment: Yes, it actually does

Answer (score 0):

I don't think, that Nikunji's answer helps. You are developing a cross platform app with xamarin. You should follow [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/notifications/android/google-cloud-messaging/) guide, instead of Microsoft Azure's one, because the Azure Guide ist **just** for Android.

Good luck!

Edit: Based on the comments, I think you you should take a look at [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) and [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/).

Comment: I am following Azure's guide, since I want to use a 3rd party messaging service. Xamarin's guide is also out-of-date :(